# Publish SQL Database from Solution in Visual Studio 2013 to Host Error

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio for Web 2013 to create an ASP.NET Web application. I have a solution I made, and that solution contains an SQL Database that I created by right clicking on the solution in the solution explorer and clicking "Add SQL Server Database."

I use this database in my solution and it works with my Web application when I run it.

[image]

What I would like to do now is publish my website and that SQL database structure to a server with godaddy.com. I downloaded the web config file for the `Web Deploy` in `VS2013`. I can now publish my website to the godaddy server - that works.

However, I am trying to also script that database to godaddy as well. I created a new empty database in godaddy and set up the connection settings in `Web Deploy`. The connection tests and validates successfully.

[image]

[image]
However, when I go to "Preview Databases" I get the following error:

Web deployment task failed. ((9/2/2014 8:08:49 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.)

```
(9/2/2014 8:08:49 PM) An error occurred when the request was processed on the remote computer.
The server experienced an issue processing the request. Contact the server administrator for more information.
```

[image]

[image]

It looks like it doesn't want to write the database to godaddy, despite all the connection settings validating in Visual Studio 2013.

If this was Visual Studio 2010, then I could use this method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465343(v=vs.100).aspx to deploy the database, but these options don't exist in `Visual Studio for Web 2013`.

Could someone help me with this? All I want to do is have a solution in `Visual Studio 2013` that has that database in it, and then when I make structural changes to the database in `Visual Studio 2013` (such as adding a table), I want those changes to be updated in the database on godaddy as well. I am having trouble figuring this out because the documentation/help online for Visual Studio 2013 is sparse.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is a problem with godaddy. I talked to them on chat about it and they could offer no solution. I eventually had to switch hosts to Arvixe which worked much better with the web deploy.

Godaddy just is not a good option for asp.net applications based on my experiences.

Answer (score 1):

It does work but only from the database project. To start with, database project deployment will also fail, but with a more useful error message. It appears they don't grant permission for you to set database options. So you have to edit your deploy profile, in the advanced settings, disable the "Deploy database properties" checkbox then save the profile.

[image: GoDaddy Database Publish Settings]

Now you can separately update your GoDaddy database via the database deployment of Visual Studio. Maybe that is better, but it's a shame the web deployment "one click" solution cannot also do the database with Go Daddy.

Maybe it's their fault, but on the other hand there documentation from Microsoft is very poor about the PublishDatabaseSettings element in their new ".pubxml" files. There are no settings I can find in the GUI or MSDN to try and get it working. Perhaps separate updates are better anyway.

Comment: Unchecking Deploy Database Properties worked for me. Thanks